HHL with eigenvalues that are not integer multiples
Pretty much all implementations of the HHL algorithms support cases where it is possible to map the eigenvalues not just to integers, but to powers of 2. Power of 2 map nicely to individual bits in an eigenvalue's binary representation and that makes the computation of the controlled rotation angles very easy when there are no shared bits in the binary representations of all eigenvalues. For example,
we can compute the angles $\theta_j$ for each integer eigenvalue $\widetilde{\lambda_j}~=~\{1, 2, \ldots \}$ as
\begin{align*}
   \theta_1 &= 2 \arcsin \frac{1}{\bf 1} = \pi, \\
   \theta_2 &= 2 \arcsin \frac{1}{\bf 2} = \frac{\pi}{3}, \\
   &\ldots \;
\end{align*}
Is there a general solution to find the rotation angles for random integer eigenvalues? Are there any references?

QPE is used inside HHL. QPE works exactly on any eigenvalue of  the form $\theta = \frac{\pi k}{2^n}$. When the eigenvalue doesn't have a finite binary expansion, it works approximately, with the probability concentrated around the best approximations for the eigenvalue. For most (all) use cases this is close enough and should only result in a negligible change to the intended state for the rest of the algorithm.
Page 42 here goes into some of the  details of this.

I’m not sure we are talking about the same thing. Yes, there is a QPE after state preparation to get the eigenvalues in superposition into the clock register. This followed by the ancillary rotations, a range of rotations to map the eigenvalues $\lambda$ to $\lambda^{-1}$. Then this is followed by a QFT and measurement.
The question is about the ancillary rotation. The angles are easy to compute if the eigenvalues are powers of two. But what if they are not - how do I compute the angles. This seems independent from your suggestions on the QPE

My point, you can't exactly do pi/3 but the algorithm will continue with pretty much the best n bit approximate of pi/3. The actual change in states is then exponentially small and should only make a negligible change to the final distribution of measurements.
